# How to hide an anchor tag and display another anchor tag in the same place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following anchor attributes defined in my JSP. Once I click the 'Add All Plans To Cart', I want the 'Add All Plans to Cart' button to hide and 'Remove All Plans From Cart' to be displayed in the same place as 'Add All Plans to Cart'.

Hide and Show is working fine. But the 'Remove All Plans From Cart' is displayed on the next line . I want it to exactly replace the 'Add All Plans To Cart' button. I tried various approaches including document.getElementById and inline,inline-block ete in my Javascript file but none of them worked.

Appreciate any inputs.Thanks.

JSP

```
<a id="selectAll" class="primaryButton btn btn-small" style="margin-left:10px">
    Add All Plans To Cart
</a>

<a id="removeAll" style="display:none" class="primaryButton btn btn-small" style="margin-left:10px">
    Remove All Plans From Cart
</a>
```

Javascript

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () 
{
    $("#selectAll").hide();
    $("#removeAll").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap buttons should preferably be used in their own element, try to wrap them inside another element which is then hidden by your code.

```
<span id="selectAll" style="margin-left:10px">
  <a class="primaryButton btn btn-small">
    Add All Plans To Cart
  </a>
</span>

<span id="removeAll" style="margin-left:10px; display:none">
  <a class="primaryButton btn btn-small">
    Remove All Plans From Cart
  </a>   
</span>
```

Comment: `hide()` does the same thing

Comment: There's no `display` property, don't you mean `.css()`?

Comment: you are right i checked that jquery .hide() does the same, edited my answer

Comment: Thanks. But I am still seeing the 'Remove All Plans From Cart' Button on the next line when I click on 'Add Plans To Cart' Button.

Comment: Also I noticed that if I edit the text from 'Remove All Plans From Cart' to 'Remove All Plans' the button is appearing in the same line with just a little space after.

Answer (score 1):

There's little wrong in your jQuery. You are missing the ending round bracket **)**  and  semicolon **;**. So your jQuery should look something like this :

***jQuery :***

```
$("#selectAll").click(function () {
     $("#selectAll").hide();
     $("#removeAll").show();
});
```

Now as i've tried in the following fiddle [***here***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/0fkxuk18/), the anchors are displayed in same position. So there might be something wrong with your css code.

*Share the css code to get in detailed solution.*

Answer (score 0):

how about float both button, if this won't help, you should public your all code somewhere, jsfiddle
for example

```
#selectAll, #removeAll {
    float: left;
}
```